# How do I form a rel canonical url in rails which accepts a ?page= param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to avoid using a gem because of the simplicity of my question.

My website has the following ?params=

```
"type" just filters by type. if this isnt specified they're all lumped together
"sort" sorts by date/whats hot/latest
"view" changes compact view/list view
"scroll" isnt even used yet, its for infinite scroll on or off which i havent put in yet
"reset" is a link when you click the logo (not the home link) that resets all session params to "all" and "whats hot" (the default)
"page" is the pagination which i think is the only really important one
```

After getting some help, I was informed `?page=` is the only really important one, as all my content can be access without any query params, EXCEPT pagination.

So now i have this:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="<%= "http://#{request.host + request.fullpath}" %>">
```

So my question is how do i modify this so it only puts the URL, and also puts ?page= if its present but ignores all the other params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to wrok

`<link rel="canonical" href="<%= "http://#{request.host + url_for(:page => params[:page]) }" %>">`

Answer (score 2):

It's 2017, I know, you could also use Rails [Auto Discovery Link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/auto_discovery_link_tag).

```
<head>
  <%= auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, your_path('your-params'), { rel: "canonical" }) %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In simplest cases that should work:

`<link rel="canonical" href="<%= "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}#{request.path}" %>">`

If you're using protocol or want to use GET params in canonical url, don't forget to add it.